# How to convert text to UTF-8 Delphi

Tags: delphi, text, utf-8

I have a function that returns an HTML page from Internet, but the Cyrillic symbols are displayed with some others unknown characters.
How can I convert the text and be able to see the normal Cyrillic symbols?

I'm with Delphi 2009 and im using indy to send HTTP request and get back response from the server.
(i think i have indy9)

This is how i take the HTML page

```
http := TIDHttp.Create(nil);
http.HandleRedirects := true;
http.ReadTimeout := 5000; 
http.Request.ContentType:='multipart/form-data'; 
param:=TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
param.AddFormField('subcat_id','501');
param.AddFormField('reg_id','1');
text:=http.Post('example.com',param);
```

I don't know if indy has any functions that gets the page with any unicode.

Comment: could possibly be a Unicode problem, what version of Delphi are you using, also could you post the code or an example of the code so we can look at it?

Comment: you need to give more details. How do you receive the data? How is it encoded?

Comment: @David, all HTTP messages are octet streams in the first place. Further handling depends on its content type and its charset parameter.

Comment: To the OP: What Delphi version, what component or library are you using for the HTTP download, how are you displaying the received text, are you seeing question marks, squares or nonsense-characters?

Comment: @User: Your question is difficult to answer until you specify a delphi version.

Comment: Yes.. sorry i didn't give much details. i edited my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given enough information, but I will try to suggest this: If possible, load the data in a Stream and then create a StringList and load it like this:

```
var
  MS:TMemoryStream;
  SL: TStringList;
(...)
begin
  MS:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  SL:=TStringList.Create;
  // Load your string to MS
  SL.LoadFromStream(MS, TEncoding.UTF8);
  (...)
  MS.Free;
  SL.Free;
end;
```

Comment if there is a problem.

Comment: not working, and i don't think that is the solution to my problem

Comment: @user759588 because this is how I've always done it. And I find StringList rather easy to work with. If there is another way, let me know :)  @TreantBG if that's the case, provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title seems to be out of sync with question body. Assuming you want to *decode* UTF-8 encoded HTML page, your friend is function [`UTF8Decode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.UTF8Decode). The opposite operation done by `UTF8Encode`. These functions were available as early as Delphi 7 (correct me if D6 applies too). Check out "See Also" section of article, there are buffer handling entry-points for more convenience too.

Comment: not working, and i don't think that is the solution to my problem

Comment: @user789546, what is you problem, then?

Answer (score 0):

Indy 9 does not support Delphi 2009.  Make sure you are using the latest Indy 10 release instead.  In Indy 10, the version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` (and `TIdHTTP.Get()`) that returns a `String` will automatically decode the data to Unicode using whatever charset is specified by the server, either in the HTTP `Content-Type` header, or in a `<meta>` tag within the HTML itself.